# call a method with a dynamic reference

Tags: java, reflection

I have a requirement, I need to call a method something like

```
SlotButtons.poiLabel1.setText(txtname.getText().toString())
```

but here poiLabel1 will be dynamically modifying. It can be modified to poiLabel2 or poiLabel3 or poiLabel4. The number comes dynamically.

Could anyone suggest me how can succeed this.

Comment: 'Dynamically modifying' how?

Comment: dynamically I should call SlotButtons.poiLabel2.setText or SlotButtons.poiLabel3.setText or ...

Comment: Maybe an array helps here? Or an `ArrayList`?

Comment: Use this inside a method and pass the label that should reflect the change?

Comment: What you want is reflection. But what you need is polymorphism.

Comment: So 'dynamically' how do you know which one you should call? Seems to me you need nothing more complex than an `if` or `switch` state,wnt. Dressing this up as 'dynamically' is just confusing the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an array.

Let's say you have an array with your buttons:

```
JLabel[]labels=new JLabel[]{
    SlotButtons.poiLabel0,
    SlotButtons.poiLabel1,
    SlotButtons.poiLabel2,
    SlotButtons.poiLabel3,
    SlotButtons.poiLabel4,
};
```

Then you could use the correct label if you know tthe index:

```
labels[yourIndex].setText(txtname.getText().toString())
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change behavior of some element dynamically on runtime, you should use [Strategy design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).